# Is centripetal force frame dependent?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, centripetal-force

Let an object is moving in a circle attached with a thread with tangential speed v .

At any instant when the object has tangential speed v in positive x direction.

Now let a car is also moving in positive x direction with a velocity v.

In frame of car the centripetal force on object is zero. So tension is also zero.

But how it can be possible tension is zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great question for understanding reference frames, acceleration, and relativity! First let me clarify your paradox...

We know that if an object has acceleration $\vec{a}$ in *some* inertial reference frame, then it must have that same acceleration in *every* inertial reference frame (e.g. a boost of a uniform velocity does not change a measured acceleration).

However, we also know that the (centripetal) acceleration required to maintain circular motion with constant speed $v$ and radius $r$ is equal to $\frac {v^2} {r}$. So if we move to a boosted frame in which $v=0$, albeit instantaneously, then the acceleration at this instant, according to this formula, vanishes!?

But the tension in the rope is the tension in the rope. It can't change with a different choice of reference frame, right?

The problem is that in the frame of the car, the object is not moving in a circle with uniform speed, and so we can't use the above formula to calculate the acceleration in the new frame. Instead we need to calculate the acceleration from first principles.

Now the formula for the velocity of the object in the moving car's frame can be found from the relative velocity addition formula:$$\vec{v}_{object|car}=\vec{v}_{object|ground}+\vec{v}_{ground|car}$$

Using the usual angular speed $\omega$, defined by $v=\omega r$, this gives:$$\vec{v}_{object|car}(t)=(v\cos\omega t) \vec{i} +(v\sin\omega t) \vec{j}- \vec{v}_{car|ground}$$
This means the acceleration in the car's frame is$$\vec{a}_{object|car}(t)=\frac {d}{dt}\vec{v}_{object|car}(t)\\=\frac {d}{dt}(v\cos\omega t) \vec{i} +\frac {d}{dt}(v\sin\omega t) \vec{j}- \frac {d}{dt}\vec{v}_{car}\\=-\omega v (\sin \omega t)\vec{i}+\omega v(\cos \omega t) \vec{j} - 0\\=-\frac {v^2} {r}(\sin \omega t)\vec{i} + \frac {v^2} {r}(\cos \omega t)\vec{j}$$So that the magnitude of the new acceleration $a_{object|car}:=|\vec{a}_{object|car}|$ is given by:$$a_{object|car}=\left[ \left( \frac {v^2}{r}\right)^2\sin^2\omega t + \left( \frac {v^2}{r}\right)^2\cos^2\omega t\right] ^\frac{1}{2}=\frac{v^2}{r}$$This shows that the old formula still works in the new (moving) frame of reference.

Comment: But directly puting values in old formula does not satisfy

Comment: Can we say in inertial frame the centripetal force is zero

Comment: @search - Centripetal force is a concept you need to grow beyond. While fictitious forces vanish in inertial frames, real forces don't. Real forces are the same in all frames (ignoring relativity). Tension is a real force.

Comment: @search The force on an object is the same in any inertial frame. What I have done here is shown how it is true in your example from first principles. Remember that in my final formula $\frac {v^2}{r}$, v is the speed measured relative to the ground, and not the speed relative to the car, so it doesn't ever vanish (or change for that matter).

Answer (score 2):

If the car is moving with a constant velocity then the rotating mass is still undergoing a centripetal acceleration in the frame of the car even though at the instant you describe the velocity of the object relative to the car is zero.
So there must be a tension in the string to provide the inward force on the object which causes the centripetal acceleration.

To illustrate that there is an acceleration note that at the next instant of time the velocity of the object relative to the car will not be zero.

In the frame of the object there is an outward pseudo force (centrifugal force) which is equal and opposite to the tension.

Comment: I am not talkimg about next instant of time . I am talking the instant when relative velocity of ball is zero

Comment: @search I know that you are not looking at the situation at the next instant of time. What I was pointing out was that **if there was no acceleration** when the velocities were the same then at the next instant of time the velocities would still be the same. So there must be an acceleration when the velocities were the same.

Answer (score 1):

The tension is not zero, we just won't call that nonzero tension the "centripetal force" any more, not in the way that term is normally used.  Generally, when you see the term "centripetal force", it refers to the force on an object moving in a circle at constant speed.  So if you go into a different frame, the object is no longer moving in a circle at constant speed, and so you don't talk about centripetal force.  However, the net force on the object is not changed by the reference frame, and the acceleration isn't either (if you choose an inertial reference frame).  If you go to non-inertial frames, you will have fictitious forces to deal with and will need a more sophisticated language to talk about them, but your example sounds restricted to inertial frames, so we can say that neither the forces nor the accelerations are any different in that frame-- but we don't have motion in a circle so we don't call it centripetal force and we don't use mv^2/r any more.  The important point is, in either frame, you will get the right answer for the motion if you keep the same tension in the rope, you just might not call it "centripetal force" in every frame.  A key thing to remember about the "centripetal force" is that it is not a force by itself, it is merely the name we use for whatever is the net force, in the *special case* when we know we have motion in a circle of radius r and speed v.  You can always take the "centripetal force" and divide it by the mass of the object, and give it the name "acceleration of the object," and note that the object's acceleration stays the same in all nonertial frames, but it will not be v^2/r unless you have motion at v around a circle of radius r.